# Spring Boot: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Following error is thrown when I running my web app.

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

The description for the thrown error as follows,

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


    Action:

    Consider the following:<br>
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
<br>    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

After referring [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074749/spring-boot-cannot-determine-embedded-database-driver-class-for-database-type), I know I have to do some changes with my `pom.xml` file. But I don't know what to change and even similar type questions on StackOverflow couldn't help me to sort this out.

My `pom.xml` as follows(when I creating project I have added "Web", "JPA", "MySQL" dependencies),

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>SL2INDUSTRY</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>SL2INDUSTRY</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

> Plese note that I don't need to deal with H2 databases in this situation so H2 is not a solution for me.

Edits:
`application.properties` file

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Comment: can you add application.properties file content in question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you read your trace of error:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

You will notice that he is trying to use hikari datasource to configure the connection to bd. What's going on?

You use spring boot 2. And by this version of spring boot has changed the default configuration.

As you can see at this address:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hikari#spring-boot-2

> In Spring Boot 2, Hikari is the default DataSource implementation.
>
> This is what’s changed from Spring Boot 1.x:
>
> · the dependency to Hikari is now automatically included in spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
>
> · the discovery algorithm that automatically determines a DataSource implementation now prefers Hikari over TomcatJDBC (see the reference manual).
>
> Thus, we have nothing to do if we want to use Hikari in an application based on Spring Boot 2.x.

And the configuration of Hikari is diferent.

Then, I imagine that you want use tomcat conection pool. You can to do:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

> This will exclude Hikari by default from your spring jpa configuration and then you will need tomcat-jdbc. The you can configure de datasource:
>
> This simple approach allows us to get Spring Boot using a Tomcat connection pool without having to write a @Configuration class and programmatically define a DataSource bean.
>
> It’s also worth noting that in this case, we’re using the H2 in-memory database. Spring Boot will autoconfigure H2 for us, without having to specify a database URL, user, and password.
>
> We just need to include the corresponding dependency in the “pom.xml” file and Spring Boot will do the rest for us.
>
> Alternatively, it’s possible to skip the connection pool scanning algorithm that Spring Boot uses and explicitly specify a connection pooling datasource in the “application.properties” file, using the “spring.datasource.type” property:

```
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
// other spring datasource properties
spring.datasource.url=...
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
...
```

Here you have the complete reference to disable Hikari, and configure tomcat:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-tomcat-connection-pool

If you want use Hikari the configuration is diferent:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hikari

But one of these two options will fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes things can be funny.

I've checked alot of solution, including the [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-failed-to-configure-data-source)
and [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221777/failed-to-configure-a-datasource-url-attribute-is-not-specified-and-no-embedd)

My mistake was, **wrong package**, I kept my Configuration Class outside the main component scan package, I placed it correctly and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities for this, but the first time there are three things you need to do.

1 - Specific compatibles versions of your dependencies on your pom.xml

2 - You need add database driverConnector on pom.xml

3 - Create an application.properties on 'src/main/resources/application.properties' directory and put your db configuration there.

application.properties (NOTE: Change de values with your database configuration)

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example

spring.datasource.username=user

spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

you can check a template here:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Comment: The reason for the error is MySQL dependency which is selected by me when I creating project

Comment: If I don't select it the project is working properly But the problem is I need to use MySQL

Comment: Probably you have a conflict between dependencies, try remove the tomcat-embed-jasper dependencie, you don't need that for use tomcat, spring-boot-starter-tomcat is enough.
If the problem persist, share your files application-spring-boot.java and application.properties

Comment: Check my response above again, I did an edit with spring.datasources properties you need to add in your application.properties.

Answer (score 0):

**if anyone has faced this issue after creating "project.jar" file**

while
every thing is fine when the project is run in IDE / STS (spring tool suit).
here is what to do:

unnecessary spaces " " in the "application.yml" file can cause this.

```
server:
  port: 8085


spring:
 datasource:
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb
  username: root
  password: root
  driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
 jpa:
   hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update
   show-sql: true
   database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
 application:
  name: STUDENT-SERVICE
```

instead of tweaking my "application.yml" file
i simply moved all my statements in "application.yml" file to
"application.properties" file and formatted the statements like required in ".properties".

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format.sql=true

spring.application.name=student-service

server.port=8085
```

**and voilà**

*(you can add params at the end of url)*
*(spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false)*

Answer (score 0):

Select project - rus as - run configuration - classpath- user entries - select your resources folders . This error because your support was not able to read your resources.propertiesfile.