# How to configure tomcat Datasource?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In build.gradle I have:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-hikari"
}
compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-jdbc', version: '9.0.21'
```

I try to configure DataSource in application.yml (located in tomcat/../resource_directory)

```
spring:
datasource:
    jdbc-url: "jdbc:oracle:thin: ...."
    username: "admin"
    password: "admin"
    driver-class-name: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    type: "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" 
    tomcat:
        initialSize: 55
        max-wait: 10000
        max-active: 50
        max-idle: 15
        min-idle: 8
        default-autoCommit: false
```

And I use @Autowired in my code. But when I debug my code I hava next:

```
log.info("dataSource: " + dataSource.toString());1
log.info("dataSourceClass: " + dataSource.getClass());2
dataSource: HikariDataSource (null) 1
dataSourceClass: class com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource 2
```

In log file I saw next:

```
Loaded 1 document from YAML resource // with correct path to file.
```

And correct loaded data:

```
spring={datasource={jdbc-url=jdbc...., username=admin, password=admin, driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, 
type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource, tomcat={initialSize=55, max- 
wait=10000, max-active=50, max-idle=15, min-idle=8, default- 
autoCommit=false}}}
```

When I put config to application.propertes in src/resources I get correct tomcat dataSource.

```
dataSource: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourc //1
dataSourceClass: class org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource//2
```

What I do wrong!?? Help me please with this confuse.

Comment: Why don't you place yml in resources like properties file.In case of both properties will be picked so keep only yml one.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually exclude:

```
com.zaxxer:HikariCP
```

**Edit:** Also, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56056330/6079171) may help too