# When I want to run my j2ee+maven+spring-boot+mysql project on idea, there comes a error

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, maven, java-ee-8

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-23 16:35:53.160 ERROR 7624 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/?user=root
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.myspring.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:34) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/?user=root
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/?user=root
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:108) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:336) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:109) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:108) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

This is the application.properties:

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/?user=root
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.database=MYSQL

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
#spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/



#spring.session.store-type=redis
#server.session.timeout=2000
#spring.redis.host=127.0.0.1
#spring.redis.port=6379
```

this is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.myspring</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring-boot-configuration-processor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId> <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

my JDBC connector version is 8.0.16, and I don't know if there is anything wrong with my database. because it seems to work well and connected well. I hope you guys can help me. I have read the cause by, but I don't know how to solve`Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl`, I don't know the reason for this problem.

and this is the img of database[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cudn.png)

thanks for @borchvm his answer solved the problem, but this is another problem

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-23 18:01:12.564 ERROR 22524 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine suitable jdbc URL


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Comment: Please provide more detail, some project config, dependency etc. no one can help you by just looking into error.

Comment: please share your application.properties file

Comment: Why don't you read : `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/?user=root`

Comment: I have read the cause by, but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: The error seems to be caused by the connection to your database: "Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl"
please check your application.properties file settings and share it too

Comment: @simonshen you might read the MySQL documentation, it's might be linked to the fact that you try to use an to much obvious password, or you try to connect on `localhost`, or another unacceptable setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` property, or rename the `spring.datasource.url` property to `spring.datasource.jdbc-url`.

I see you are using the HikariCP library, maybe you should check the documentation for more information:

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#initialization

Comment: thanks for the advice the problem, it sames to be solved. but there comes another problem'''Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine suitable jdbc url


Action:

Consider the following:
 If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
 If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).'''

Comment: thanks for the advice on the problem, it has been solved. but there comes another problem, if you can help me with the other problem, I 'll be grateful for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=   
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

you have another post here with the same problem, check it:

[Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221777/failed-to-configure-a-datasource-url-attribute-is-not-specified-and-no-embedd)

Answer (score 0):

the new problem can be solved as this`@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`,just find the `xxxApplication.java` and my is DemoApplication.java,add`(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`behind`@SpringBootApplication`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89fOd.png)

Comment: when it comes to a new problem and the old one has been resolved, you should create a new post with that problem and not mix it up. I also appreciate a positive score if my solution helped you. Thank you.