# Failed to determine a suitable driver class spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I run my Spring Boot project, I get this error:

> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
> no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
>
> Consider the following:
>
> If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on
> the classpath.
> If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile
> you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

I got this dependencies in my pom.xml file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

This error occurred when I tried to change my Spring Boot version to 2.5.5.

Comment: How does your jdbc url look like?

Comment: jdbc:mysql://10.54.32.44:3306

Comment: So you have spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.54.32.44:3306 in your application.properties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221777/failed-to-configure-a-datasource-url-attribute-is-not-specified-and-no-embedd)

Comment: @Alien no,it's not fixing my problem

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes

Comment: can you please show your application.properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, this dependency was deleted and that's why this issue occurred.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```