# how can i fix this problem , i want to conect my application spring boot with Mysql database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

i want solution please

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221777/failed-to-configure-a-datasource-url-attribute-is-not-specified-and-no-embedd) can help.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have added mysql dependences in your class path.

in your application.yaml or application.properties ensure that the connection String to the database is clear set through the properties;
spring.datasource.url, spring.datasource.username and spring.datasource.password

Comment: thank's but I tried all these solutions but no result