# Springboot: attempting to build the project and connect to PostgreSQL: Deprecated Gradle features were used incompatible with Gradle 9.0

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, gradle, groovy

I am using (If it matters):
Windows 11
VS code for making the java code
CMD to run and build the project

I stumbled upon this article/guide to create what I though was just what I needed, but I've run into a roadblock and I am out of ideas as to what to do.
The guide: https://talesofdancingcurls.medium.com/spring-boot-with-postgresql-a-step-by-step-guide-c451848f0184

Using spring initializr I made a project exactly as was said in the guide.

I followed the guide to the end with the only adjustments being that I modified and removed functions and variables that I knew I was not going to need.

Now I attempted to run `./gradlew build`
"Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0." (NOTE: I have Gradle 8.4 installed which I downgraded from 8.5 initially thinking that would help)
Not a very helpful error, but the html report it created is a tad bit more detailed.

In the HTML report I found
"Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class"

Below I will put all the java files I've modified/created or matter:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**SmiTbackendProjectApplication.java**

```
package com.example.SMITbackend;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class SmiTbackendProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SmiTbackendProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Contact.java**

```
package com.example.SMITbackend.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact")
public class Contact {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String realName;
    private String codeName;
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

**ContactController.java**

```
package com.example.SMITbackend.controller;

import com.example.SMITbackend.entity.Contact;
import com.example.SMITbackend.service.ContactService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/contact")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
public class ContactController {
    
    private final ContactService contactService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Contact>> getAllContacts(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(contactService.getAllContacts());
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<Contact> saveContact(@RequestBody Contact contact)
    {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(contactService.saveContact(contact));
    }
}
```

**ContactRepository.java**

```
package com.example.SMITbackend.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.example.SMITbackend.entity.Contact;

public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Integer>{
    
}
```

**ContactService.java**

```
package com.example.SMITbackend.service;

import com.example.SMITbackend.entity.Contact;
import com.example.SMITbackend.repository.ContactRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ContactService {

    private final ContactRepository contactRepository;

    public List<Contact> getAllContacts(){
        return contactRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Contact saveContact (Contact contact){
        Contact savedContact = contactRepository.save(contact);

        return contact;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: springboot
  jackson:
    property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE
  flyway:
    locations: classpath:/db/migration
    schemas: contacts
    baselineOnMigrate: true
    enabled: true
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/contacts?currentSchema=contacts
    username: postgres
    password: {my password}
```

After a quick google search for the "driver class" issue I found this:[Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221777/failed-to-configure-a-datasource-url-attribute-is-not-specified-and-no-embedd)

I was confused as there was a driverclass mentioned in the properties. I decided to add the "spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" to the end of my properties file, since what is the worst that could happen.

this seems have gotten rid of the error and was now replaced with:

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-18T05:31:02.164-08:00 ERROR 11608 --- [    Test worker] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate ...

I also ran `./gradlew build --warning-mode all`
The error was different, but the link it gave me to fix the deprecation issue was not helpful.
"The automatic loading of test framework implementation dependencies has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. Declare the desired test framework directly on the test suite or explicitly declare the test framework implementation dependencies on the test's runtime classpath. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: [https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#test_framework_implementation_dependencies"](https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#test_framework_implementation_dependencies%22)
I don't understand what I am supposed to change/remove/replace and where if so.

Comment: The problem is your `application.properties` either make it a proper properties file i.e adding things like `spring.datasource.url=<uour url>` etc. or rename it to `application.yaml` as that is what you are using. The gradle warnings have nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: As I am quite new to springboot and java as a whole. Could you show me how to or point to a resource that could potentially help me?

Comment: As mentioned rename your file to `application.yaml`.  This has nothing to do with java, but rather naming. Basically you tried renaming a PDF to DOCX and tried to open it with MS Word. A properties file and yaml files are different things as well and need to be read using different mechanisms.

Comment: My bad... I attempted to "make it a proper properties file" and ended up somehow missing the part where you said to just rename the file.

Thank you for the help.